# On macOS Monterey, cannot create shortcut actions

Tags: swift, macos, shortcut

I'm trying to follow the [**Meet Shortcuts for macOS**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10232/) and I keep getting stuck on the stack where you have

```
class IntentHandler: NSObject, CreateTaskIntentHandling {
    func handle(intent: CreateTaskIntent, completion: @escaping (CreateTaskIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        let title = intent.title!
        let dueDate = intent.dueDate!
    
        let task = createTask(name: title, due: dueDate)
    
        let response = CreateTaskIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
        response.task = task
        completion(response)
    }
}
```

The problem is the line `let task = createTask(name: title, due: dueDate)` where is that suppose to come from, also its type is Task which is already defined, so I trained using a different name, I don't know how I am suppose to create the CreateTaskIntentResponse.task class, and there doesn't seem to be any instruction to do so, I also had a few problems with it all being beta so there would be different versions of the same method, and a field in the intent file needed to be fill in.

Comment: Did you construct the intent definition file as shown in the video?

Comment: Yes it all compiles fine, I have tried 5 times now, but I always end up with this let task = createTask(name: title, due: dueDate) method that won't compile because its not defined, how am I suppose to implement it, I changed my type to NoteTask to avoid confusion with Task, but the compiler will not let me create a NoteTask, and it will not let be assign my NoteTask to the response, what is NoteTask or Task suppose to be, how do I create it? I wish they would just let me download the project and let me look for myself.

Comment: I downloaded SoupChefAcceleratingAppInteractionsWithShortcuts, and tried to compile that but that fails, also the video doesn't tell you want your NSApplicationDelegate function is suppose to do or your IntentsExtension method is suppose to do, it incomplete as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what the createTask function is suppose to look like

```
func createTask(name: String, due: DateComponents) -> Task {
    let task = Task(identifier: "<appid>.createTask", display: name)
    task.dueDate = due
    return task
}
```

Where appid is your application id I think.